# Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws4'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, compiler-errors, next.js, runtime-error

My project have two folder

1. client
2. server

both client and server runs but sometime on client when i visit any page so on the terminal the following errors shows how can fix these errors

```
wait  - compiling... 
warn  -

../server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/mongodb_aws.js 
Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws4' in 'C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\auth'

../server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'mongodb-client-encryption' in 'C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations'
 
../server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

../server/node_modules/require_optional/index.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 
../server/node_modules/require_optional/index.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 
../server/node_modules/require_optional/index.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem with mongodb, unfortunatly it warn for modules that are not strictly required.
An easy and quick solution to your problem, in your next.config file ignore these warnings:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      "mongodb-client-encryption": false ,
      "aws4": false
    };

    return config;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error too. All I did was run the below command (which installs the aws4 module) and all was solved.

```
npm install aws4
```